# Embest AT91SAM9G45 board compatibility with OPENCV

Tags: c, arm9

Hi i am new in embedded field, please tell me whether OpenCv files are compatible with the Embest AT91SAM9G45, ARM9 board.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but I don't see why not. Judging from the Atmel page on your chip there is a development studio. It doesn't explicitly say but I think it supports C++ and if so you can compile OpenCV using Cmake and that particular compiler.